# css background image (sprite) not respecting caching headers

Tags: css, image, caching, http-headers, background-image

I have a background image used as sprite inside a site. This Image is normally cached by browsers. What I tried to do is using etag and last-modified headers to refresh that image when it must be updated (it changes a lot).

What I see, is that the image is not refreshed when the server sends a new image to the client.

Having the exact same image href inside an img element, seems to work perfect.

I cannot find the reason for this issue nor can I find a solution.

Comment: If you inspect the response headers for your image, are the etag and last-modified headers what you expect them to be?

Comment: Yes they are! The only problem is that the image is not updated. Even if I refresh the page (F5) the background image stays the same. The background image updates only if I clear the cache (or hit Ctrl+F5 on firefox)